# MySQL Select rows having sum(criteria1) <> sum(criteria2)

Tags: mysql

I'm sure the answer is out there somewhere, but can't find it...

One table stores logged hours for employees, classified by type (type = Project or Task).
For each day, I can have hours logged on multiple tasks.

By doing a simple sum and grouping I can get the total hours per type and per day, but I'd like to go one step further:
display only the "error cases" where sum(hours) per Project is different than sum(hours) for all Tasks for a given date.

```
mysql> select sum(logged), type, date from `hoursLog` group by idEmployee, date, type;
+-------------+----------+----------+
| sum(logged) | type     | date     |
+-------------+----------+----------+
|     0.8     | Project  | 20160525 |
|     1.0     | Task     | 20160525 |
|     0.3     | Project  | 20160526 |
|     0.3     | Task     | 20160526 |
|     0.3     | Project  | 20160527 |
|     0.5     | Task     | 20160527 |
+-------------+----------+----------+
```

From the above table, I want only the dates 20160525 and 20160527, for which the sum is different.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
 SUM(IF(`type`='Task',logged,0)) task_hours,
 SUM(IF(`type`='Project',logged,0)) project_hours,
 date 
FROM `hoursLog` 
GROUP by idEmployee, date
HAVING task_hours <> project_hours
```

But I am not sure if you really need `GROUP BY idEmployee`. I guess this works now just because you have few records in test DB with only 1 employee involved. Do you need time summarized per person? or just per date?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Simple and efficient :)  Yes, I do need the `GROUP BY idEmployee`, as the real table has many more entries.
Thanks again for the fresh look on this.